# Is there a way to force pages to load slowly?

Tags: website-design, usability-testing, tools, browser

I'm  developing a website and want to test the user experience when some of the images load slowly. Obviously I'm doing everything I can to make assets small and load quickly, but there are slow networks and little hiccups (especially in mobile) that are out of my control.

I know I can delete my cache every time I want to test the page, but not only is this a little bit of a pain, but my connection is fast enough to still load images in a near-instant. The images are being loaded from a CDN.

Can't seem to find anything - has anyone come across something to help me out or have any other ideas of how to slow down my image for testing purposes?

Comment: Not sure how this relates to UX.

Comment: Speed is an essential part of the experience, not limited to, but especially on mobile. It is often referred to as a 'non-functional requirement' and something that development usually is supposed to take care of. Still it's part of the experience and hence related to UX.

Comment: believe this should be on http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I bridge my network connection through a IPCop virtual machine, to allow exactly for this (IPCop allows to limit your bandwidth, making even your LAN slow without tweaking any local parameter). On a side note, this isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow (it would probably be considered offtopic as a question asking to "recommend or find off-site tools")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple thing you can do is run [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and go to Rules > Performance > Simulate Modem Speeds.

Another option if your site is public is to use [webpagetest.org](http://www.webpagetest.org/) and change the connection speed under advanced options before you run your test.

Comment: Charles http://kevinlangdon.com/serviceCapture/ and Service Capture http://www.charlesproxy.com/ also work.

Comment: Although it's not exactly what I was looking for, it got me 90% of the way there and is a feature I never knew Fiddler had. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an application that emulates slow connection: it limits the bandwidth to test sites as if they were seen on dial-up or adsl:  [Sloppy](http://www.dallaway.com/sloppy/).